# Health and magnetic influence of notebook

Tags: mental-health

How is harmful to keep laptop on the legs or near of the body in terms of magnetic influence?

Answer (score 4):

Magnetic, no.  As Variax points out.

A potential risk would be one of heat from the battery and components within the laptop itself, which gets hotter as the laptop works harder, especially if the cooling vents are blocked (by clothing, cushions, cats, etc.).

Heat is a form of radiation, but it's just that - heat.

Comment: Citations are expected here.

Comment: @CareyGregoryI don't believe that basic common sense requires citations, which is why I ceased contributing to this stack many months ago.

Comment: You're welcome to join the debate on that issue in meta.

Comment: I think you'll find that I did.  Then I gave up.  Then I stopped contributing to this stack and subsequently felt a lot happier about things.  The stack here is clearly not a good fit for me (and it seems a lot of other people).

Comment: I understand. I'm not entirely in agreement with the policy either.

Answer (score 1):

The electromagnetic radiation emitted by a laptop is completely harmless, both by its amount and by its spectrum. No harmful effects occur from this kind of exposition, regardless of the affected area or the time of exposure.

Comment: The wifi has real health risks, plenty of studies available. You can disable the service, I suggest you use plug a ethernet cable(you can buy it on ebay 300 meters too if you want and share with friends/family,but you need special crimper and the small piece at the end)

Comment: @HerbalResearcher Wifi does not have "real health risks." If you want to make the case that it does, provide an answer with citations for all these studies you think exist.

Answer (score 1):

The heat can increase scrotal temperature, which may influence male fertility [1](https://academic.oup.com/humrep/article/20/2/452/603276/Increase-in-scrotal-temperature-in-laptop-computer). However, that study is from 2005 and laptops are much less hot these days so I would not think its that much of an issue...

[Increase in scrotal temperature in laptop computer users](https://academic.oup.com/humrep/article/20/2/452/603276/Increase-in-scrotal-temperature-in-laptop-computer)